# Set static control at the top of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` and inside it, I want to add `FlowLayoutPanel`

So I added it and it works, but now I want to know how can I make that FlowLayoutPanel static at the top of  `TableLayoutPanel` because when I scroll `TableLayoutPanel` the `FlowLayoutPanel` just disappear because is at the top of the list. Is it possible to set static control inside a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: Then don't add it to the TLP? You can `Dock.Top` the FLP and `Dock.Fill` the TLP. However it depends on your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way adding frozen row to TableLayoutPanel. But you can make this:

Don't add FlowLayoutPanel on that TableLayoutPanel. Instead, use another TableLayoutPanel with 2 rows and 1 column. Add FlowLayoutPanel to the top of the new TableLayoutPanel and add your actual TableLayoutPanel to 2nd row with autoscroll enabled. At the image: the blue one is outer TableLayoutPanel, the black one is FlowLayoutPanel and the gray one is inner TableLayoutPanel. I set Margins as 5 to show all objects, you can set Margins as 0.

[image: Example Image]